# str_extract captures only one instance of recurring keyword

Tags: r, regex, string, text-extraction, stringr

When I use `str_extract()` on a string with recurring instances of a certain keyword, it captures only one of them.

```
> str_extract("1234cAc5678cAc90123", ".....A.....")
[1] "1234cAc5678"
```

I have two questions:

1. What is the criterion of choosing one rather than the other? (i.e. "5678cAc9012")
2. How to make R extract instances each and every time one occurs, regardless of whether the strings overlap or not?

---

str_extract_all gave 2 instances when the strings are not overlapping, which means str_extract captures just the first instance of the recurring string.

```
> str_extract_all("1234cAc5678cAc90123", "...A...")
[[1]]
[1] "34cAc56" "78cAc90"
```

Are there any other function that may show all occurrences even when they overlap, like this:

```
[1] "1234cAc5678"
[2] "5678cAc9012"
```

Or even this:

```
> str_extract("0123A456A7890", "....A....")
[1] "0123A456A"
[2] "A456A7890"
```

Comment: I realized that we can capture all instances by reducing the criteria to just "A" : > str_extract_all("1234cAc5678cAc90123", "A"), and work my way upwards. Takes some time to discover which patterns got excluded when the data is large, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are looking for overlapping matches, then use the `stri_match_all`

```
library(stringi)
stri_match_all_regex(str1, "(?=(.{5}A.{5}))")[[1]][,2]
#[1] "1234cAc5678" "5678cAc9012"
```

Or if we are using `stringr`, which call the `stringi`, then use `str_match_all`

```
str_match_all(str1, "(?=(.{5}A.{5}))")[[1]][,2]
#[1] "1234cAc5678" "5678cAc9012"

str_match_all("0123A456A7890", "(?=(.{4}A.{4}))")[[1]][,2]
#[1] "0123A456A" "A456A7890"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "1234cAc5678cAc90123"
```